# its possible to attach dateClick on view-specific options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the view specific options of FullCalendar v4 to add a custom dateClick callback only in the dayGridMonth view, someone know if this option its possible?
What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the navLinks option, but I want the user to change the calendar view to the day view on that view only, in the day view if he/she clicks, it will add an event, etc.

Comment: As per the dateClick docs, the data provided to the callback includes information about the current view, so you can just decide within the callback itself whether you wish to proceed with your action, based on what type of view is currently being displayed

Comment: P.s. adding events is supposed to be done via the select callback, not dateClick. This gives the user proper flexibility about selecting times as well as dates, and also separates this functionality away from the dateClick function which, as you've discussed, you want to use for other purposes some of the time

Comment: @ADyson hmm, thx alot, I didnt saw that information on docs, after your comment I could get the view info, now Im having problems to change the view, every try I do at the console returns me UNDEFINED or NOT A FUNCTION

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately without seeing enough of your code to be able to reproduce the error message I really can't comment on what you've done wrong. As I'm sure you can appreciate, it's quite hard to fix something you can't see.